# Swinging Beam example from Help. Not Understanding/Not Working

Tags: finite-element-method, solidmechanics

To help me understand finite element analysis with Mathematica I have been reading the Finite Element Method User Guide in Help and am stuck on the example in Coupled PDEs. Here there is a static beam problem and a swinging beam problem.

I have taken the code from the static beam problem and this works nicely

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariable", 
     "Space"} -> {{u, v}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData["Space" -> ToNumericalRegion[mesh]];

bcDu0 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0];
bcDv0 = DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == 0];
bcNL = NeumannValue[-1, x == 5];
initBCs = 
  InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {{bcDu0}, {bcDv0, bcNL}}];

diffusionCoefficients = 
  "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-(Y/(1 - \[Nu]^2)), 
        0}, {0, -((Y (1 - \[Nu]))/(2 (1 - \[Nu]^2)))}}, {{0, -((
         Y \[Nu])/(1 - \[Nu]^2))}, {-((Y (1 - \[Nu]))/(
         2 (1 - \[Nu]^2))), 
        0}}}, {{{0, -((Y (1 - \[Nu]))/(2 (1 - \[Nu]^2)))}, {-((
         Y \[Nu])/(1 - \[Nu]^2)), 
        0}}, {{-((Y (1 - \[Nu]))/(2 (1 - \[Nu]^2))), 
        0}, {0, -(Y/(1 - \[Nu]^2))}}}} /. {Y -> 10^3, \[Nu] -> 33/100};
initCoeffs = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, {diffusionCoefficients}];


methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
split = {#[[1]] + 1 ;; #[[2]], #[[2]] + 1 ;; #[[3]]} &[
   methodData["IncidentOffsets"]];
discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = discretePDE["SystemMatrices"];

DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, discreteBCs];

solution = LinearSolve[stiffness, load];
uif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, solution[[split[[1]]]]];
vif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, solution[[split[[2]]]]];
dmesh = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}];
```

I can plot results as follows using

```
 mesh["Wireframe"]
ContourPlot[uif[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
ContourPlot[vif[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Show[{
  mesh["Wireframe"],
  dmesh["Wireframe"[
    "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}]
```

to give

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All this is good but it goes wrong for me when I move onto the swinging beam which modifies the above code. I can't get this to run even if I copy directly from Help. Here is the relevant set-up code from Help

```
    massCoefficients = "MassCoefficients" -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
initCoeffs = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[vd, 
   sd, {diffusionCoefficients, massCoefficients}];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = discretePDE["SystemMatrices"];
rayleighDamping = 0.1*mass + 0.04*stiffness;
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, rayleighDamping, mass}, 
  discreteBCs];
dof = methodData["DegreesOfFreedom"];
init = dinit = ConstantArray[0, {dof, 1}];
sparsity = 
  ArrayFlatten[{{mass["PatternArray"], 
     mass["PatternArray"]}, {rayleighDamping["PatternArray"], 
     rayleighDamping["PatternArray"]}}];
```

It is the next bit of the solution code that gets stuck. The time monitor stops  around 0.00158 so I have tried running the code to 0.0015 rather than 45 as in Help but it still gets stuck.

```
 Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]]
AbsoluteTiming[
 tif = NDSolveValue[{
    mass.u''[ t] + rayleighDamping.u'[ t] + stiffness.u[ t] == load
    , u[ 0] == init, u'[ 0] == dinit}, u, {t, 0, 0.0015}
   , Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
   , Jacobian -> {Automatic, Sparse -> sparsity}
   , EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)
   ]]
```

Are there any suggestions for how to make this work?

Comment: All your code seems to execute fine on my system (MMA 10.2 Win7-64). I obtain at the end an interpolating function with the full 45 s domain (it takes roughly 9 seconds to do so). I don't really know what to do with that function to check whether it is correct, but at least it seems to run error-free.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for looking at this. I have MMA 10.0.2 and Win7-64. It definitely does not give me answers in over 20 minutes and I can't abort it either. So perhaps it is a version problem. If someone could check it who has 10.0.2 that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me in 10.0.2 on Linux and it takes about 11 seconds. Do you perhaps have a variable defined that should not be. If you copy your own code from this post into a fresh notebook and a fresh kernel, does it still not work?

Comment: @user21 and MarcoB  I have checked yet again and done exactly as you suggested copying from here to a fresh kernel and it still gets stuck. Is this a diagnostic point: the displayed time starts small and produces some negative values before going positive and sticking at 0.00158...? Also if I set the time to less than this value i.e. 0.0015 the code still does not stop. As MMA freezes and I have to exit and restart I can't think of a way of capturing these time values. Thanks for your continued interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that my version of Mathematica was corrupted. I did a Shift+Control while starting Mathematica ([see here for good instructions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57671/trial-version-10-vs-version-10-prerelease-13))  and the code now works perfectly. Thanks to user21 and MarcoB for confirming that the code  works. Wolfram Support also confirmed that the code works and suggested a restart.

Out of interest I compared a benchmark from before the Shift+Control to after the restart. The benchmark is found by running

```
    Needs["Benchmarking`"]
    BenchmarkReport[]
```

Before restart:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

After restart:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see I have gone from anti-penultimate to top-of-the-heap!

Thanks for the help

Comment: +1 for making the effort to write a detailed self-answer with a nice link