# Manipulate After upgrading to windows 10

Tags: manipulate, windows

After upgrading to windows 10, whenever I run any kind of Manipulate function in Mathematica 10.1, the program freezes. This can be as simple as Manipulate[x,{x,0,5}].

Does anyone else have this issue? I have reinstalled Mathematica 10.1, and checked that my drivers are up to date, so I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: Try these steps: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57674/12