# Mathematica hangs on “Initializing kernels…“ at startup

Tags: kernel-startup, configuration

My Mathematica 10.0 doesn’t start anymore (hangs while “Initializing kernels…“). I already reduced the problem to the file `pacletSiteData_10.pmd2` in `~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration`—if I remove it Mathematica starts again but recreates the file.

Can I somehow get Mathematica to be a little more verbose (there are no log files in `~/.Mathematica/Logs`)?

Any recommendations?

Best regards,
Florian

Comment: Have you tried [How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default configuration?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)

Comment: Check here too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57674/12

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Lou, Szabolcs: Obviously I alreadytried removing the user configuration.

Comment: @Sjoerd That was the right hint, thank you!

Comment: I think this is likely a duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92931/12  @ilian says that a buggy paclet update wash pushed just now that causes exactly this problem.