# Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels

Tags: bugs, front-end, system, kernel-startup, paclets

**Bug caused by paclet update and fixed by paclet update.**

---

I updated to Windows 10 and have been running *Mathematica* fine on it for over a month.  For some reason, it has just stopped working. I don't remember any Windows updates occurring which would have caused this, and I didn't change any settings in *Mathematica* for weeks.

When I end task on the kernel, it gives the message 'Unable to launch kernel system'. Has anyone else has experienced this in Windows 10?

Comment: This happened to me on Windows 7.

Comment: It just happened to me with *Mathematica 10.0.0* on Windows 8.1 The below fix works fine in this case too.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes, there was a recently pushed incorrect paclet update that will cause this startup hang. All platforms can be affected, not just Windows.

For a workaround, start a standalone kernel (`WolframKernel.exe` on [Windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94036/more-information-about-solving-mathematica-10-0-freezing-issue/94045#94045), `WolframKernel` in a terminal on Linux; on Mac you will need the full path to the kernel binary, typically a location like `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel`) and evaluate

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]

PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]
```

which should allow a normal startup afterwards.

It is also possible to

- disable your computer's network connection
- start *Mathematica*
- turn on the network connection
- evaluate

  `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]`

  `PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]`

after which things should work again, even if the network connection is left enabled.

**Update**

As of this edit, the broken paclet is no longer on the server. For those still experiencing the startup hang, the steps above still work, but the easiest fix would be to either delete the entire `Paclets` folder or just the `pacletSiteData_10.pmd2` file, which is located in the user base directory, typically under

- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Configuration` on Windows
- `~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration` on Linux
- `~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration` on Mac OS X

Comment: Just FYI - It would be courteous to send an email informing users when a push is done, especially with fix information ASAP after discovery of a problem that breaks the system! This is the second time this year of paclet updates breaking my system.

Comment: For the Mac, open terminal and type: /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel

Comment: Just testing this now, it fails for me with: 

PacletInstall::dwnld: An error occurred downloading paclet CloudObject-10.3.760 from site 
    http://pacletserver.wolfram.com: Network error. Failure when receiving data from the peer

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Very good point, running 'WolframKernel' simply does not work (it causes 'dlopen(/Users/SystemFiles, 1): image not found') even though the former just points to the later). It worked for me (`In[1]:=PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]` `(*=> Out[1]= Paclet[CloudObject, 10.3.760, <>]*)` for MMA 10.0.2.0.

Comment: @JGregoryMoxness Sorry for the inconvenience caused by this unfortunate oversight. Our paclet updates are carefully tested and usually go much more smoothly, due to their frequency it may be unfeasible to email every user on every update.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Must have been a transient network error, because the same step succeeded on your second try in the notebook.

Comment: @mmal I have updated the answer to reflect that a symbolic link to `WolframKernel` will not work on OS X, one needs the full path to the kernel binary.

Comment: @JGregoryMoxness, illian -- My Mac OS updates are handled by requiring the me to click a button (or two) to start the update. MS Office, Google Picasa, Flash, etc. also are only updated when I click OK.  Is it really not feasible for my local kernel to query me before proceeding with an update?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Personally I would like to have this feature (as well as the ability to download only the documentation needed on demand), but it is not implemented within the current mechanism.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Thank you for your help. Now, I manage to open mathematica. However, I still receive this warning when I open it : INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: Printing|c|3547
Information:GetDefaultPrinterDevice failed with Windows System Error 12019: Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research
It is a bit strange. Do you have ideas to correct it ?

Comment: @Bendesarts Perhaps try changing your Windows default printer setting; if that doesn't help, it's best to get in touch with technical support.

Comment: @ilian You sure could email us when you disable our installations like this, instead of letting your paying customers spend hours searching for a solution. You don't seem to hesitate to send marketing emails.

Comment: @Italianice They should email non-premier service users too

Comment: Thanks, for your complete solution. I actually have performed it and it works. However, the problem is that everytime that I want to run Mathematica I have to delete the Paclets in the configuration folder (~\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Configuration). I also uninstall my Mathematica 11.3 completely, by deleting the relevant folders but even for the first time I couldn't open the program and it stucks at "initializing Kernel connections". For the final attempt, I uninstalled it completely and installed the 10.4 version but the same exist. I don't know what to do.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

I'm adding an alternate solution for Mac, as the suggested answer did not work for me. It might be due to me force quitting it prior to looking for a solution.

This method is a bit of a scorched earth process though.

In Finder go to `~/Library/Mathematica`. Once there delete the `Paclets` folder.

Next start up Mathematica again. Create a blank worksheet. Then evaluate `PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]`.

Wait for the `Out` response before quitting Mathematica.

Comment: This is a good solution, I would recommend deleting just the `~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets` folder, so it won't be necessary to reactivate.

Comment: cheers. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Simon - I had the same problem, your solution worked fine!

Comment: Worked for me on Mac OS 10.8.5, with Mathematica 10.0.1.0