# Mathematica notebook autocompletion completely disappears

Tags: front-end, notebooks, autocomplete, version-11.2

Just as what is described in the title, the notebook behaves as if it were originally designed to not have the autocompletion functionality at all. Neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> nor <kbd>F2</kbd> works. Furthermore, reinstalling Mathematica does not help, either.

What measures could be taken that possibly help to recover the autocompletion functionality? I suspect that some items in "Option Inspector" might be responsible but I can not find them.

---

It seems that quite a few people encounter this problem recently.

But, for now, the "`$UserBaseDirectory` deletion / renaming methods" cannot thoroughly settle this issue, can they?

Comment: Hard to say without more details. Provide the version of MMA and the system running it. Does this happen in a fresh-started kernel in a new empty notebook? Try [clean-starting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94020/26956) Mathematica, maybe there's some lingering user settings not being removed upon reinstall. I experience that `Dynamic` functionality sometimes interferes with autocomplete, but that shouldn't be the case in a fresh notebook and kernel.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Windows 10 + MMA 11.2. It happens even in a freshly started one.

Comment: I'm not running this particular combination, so I can't check for myself. Most likely this is something very localized to your machine, in which case this is off-topic here and should be addressed to Wolfram support.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I think I find the problem source. It is an unofficial package (http://github.com/rolfmertig/Shortcuts). It is very strange that the package causes this problem just recently.

Comment: @Kuba So far I have no definite conclusion on the origin. And I put forward my suspicion, neither necessary nor sufficient conditions. Unfortunately, every now and then I suffer from the annoying symptom, even with the "$UserBaseDirectory deletion therapy".

Comment: @AlexanderZeng it looks like it is more complicated. Anyway, I've update the answer and I will try to link all related question as duplicates of this one.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had same problem yesterday. M stopped doing auto-complete for no reason. I deleted my `$UserBaseDirectory` and when I restarted M, it worked  and auto-complete was back. This is very strange. I am using 11.2 on windows 7. I did not do anything myself to cause this.

Comment: Just mentioning [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406) page as it addresses one of the questions (some items in "Option Inspector" might be responsible ...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PacletUpdate["EntityFramework"]`

should resolve the issue at this point.

Comment: Yes that worked for me! Clean Start didn't help for me.

Comment: It seems that I can use `Shortcuts` again. Could you please explain what happens?

Comment: Not sure, just saw the answer on the other forum.

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same problem today (I have Mathematica 11.2 and Windows 10): the autocomplete suddenly disappeared and neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> worked.

I don't have any additional packages installed; only the basic Mathematica. I tried clean-starting and that didn't work.

I managed to get autocomplete to work again by **deleting the `$UserBaseDirectory` and restarting**:

See also

- [tutorial/ConfigurationFiles](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html)
- [How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default configuration?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)

I hope this helps!

It appears that `` Shortcuts` `` package can be involved but it is not clear how, see update in:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824/5478

so before you delete whole `$UserBaseDirectory` you can try:

```
Needs @ "Shortcuts`"
UninstallShortcuts[]
(*+restart*)
```

Comment: So you didn't have ``Shortcuts` `` package installed?

Comment: I have the same problem since this morning. I don't have the shortcuts package installed.

Comment: I don't think I had `Shortcuts`` installed (I am new to Mathematica and only installed from the iso nothing more).