# Autocomplete and Information icon missing

Tags: autocomplete

Mathematica Version 11.2 desktop / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Autocomplete and Information icon no longer appear.

[Practicalities of Using the Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/practicalities-of-using-the-wolfram-language.html)

Is there some setting someplace where I might have mistakenly disabled it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had the same issue on a Linux machine yesterday. Deleting the .Mathematica directory fix it for me . But then you have to type in the activation key again. Unfortunately I don't now where that directory is located on a Windows machine.

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160588/mathematica-notebook-autocompletion-completely-disappears, this might help - I had the same problem, and got it fixed this way

Comment: `PacletUpdate["EntityFramework"]` then restart the front.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help.

I received the following two solutions from Mathematica Technical Support.

I used Solution 1. It worked. Fortunately, Solution 1 did not require typing in an activation key.

The next day, I received Solution 2 from Mathematica Technical Support. Solution 2 should be easier. I did not test it since Solution 1 had already corrected the issue.

Note that the following will display the User Base Directory:

Help menu | System information... menu item | Front End tab | Directories section | User Base Directory

******************* Solution 1 (Harder Solution )*******************

Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.

Can you please try these steps:

1) Close Mathematica.

2) Renaming your $UserBaseDirectory.

By default (for Windows 10), it is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica

3) Try using the autocompletion feature again.

******************* Solution 2 (Easier Solution) ******************

This is an easier process to resolve the behavior:

1) In Mathematica, evaluate

PacletUpdate["EntityFramework"]

2) Restart Mathematica

This has just been tested this morning.

Comment: They would be more useful saying what exactly goes wrong, I have a lot of stuff in user base dir that I don't want to drop. And now I have to pick one after another to check.

Comment: @John You can ask the support for more detailed information about offending subfolder of `$UserBaseDirectory`.

Comment: Kuba and Popkov - I just updated Answer 1 with Solution 2 which is easier. Please let me know if it works for you.