# More Information About Solving Mathematica 10.0 Freezing Issue

Tags: kernel-startup

I am aware now that Mathematica 10.0 is having difficulty with freezing during its startup while displaying the message "Initializing kernels..."

The question is answered here:

[Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels/92932#92932)

Unfortunately, I'm just a grad student in my university's math department, and I have very little knowledge about programming in general.  Can somebody please explain to me the steps that I would have to take to start a standalone kernel, and what exactly a paclet is, and how to evaluate it?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: The operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: Looks like you should ask that in a comment in the Q&A you referred to.

Answer (score 5):

These are the same steps as in [(92931)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931) with a little bit of added detail for Windows.

- Make sure any running (or hanging) copies of *Mathematica* are closed
- Navigate to the installation directory, this is typically some location 
  like `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0.2`
- Double-click `WolframKernel.exe` to start a standalone kernel
- At the `In[1]:=` prompt, type `PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

- Close the kernel window and launch the main program (`Mathematica.exe`) as usual