# Mathematica 10.0.1 freezes at Initializing kernels

Tags: initialization

I tried to evaluate `PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]` in *WolframKernel.exe*, but got the error:

> PacletInstall::dwnld: 
>      An error occurred downloading paclet CloudObject-10.3.760 from site http://pacletserver.wolfram.com: File not found on server.

I changed my default setting for the printer, but doesn't work either.

What should I do now ?

Comment: Can you try unplugging your internet cable, launching *Mathematica*, plugging in the cable and executing the `PacletUpdate[...]` command.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. After unplugging internet cable Mathematica still doesn't initialize and won't launch.

Comment: It doesn't work. I just remove "pacletData_10.0.0.0_7270004994179419278.pmd2" and "pacletSiteData_10.pmd2" and then Mathematica initialize successfully. Those two files then appear again. Looks like I have to remove them again and again before I want to start Mathematica.

Comment: I think this error is because the broken paclet has just been removed from the server. Try evaluating `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]` first.

Comment: @ilian You should post this as an answer not a comment. It worked for me.

Comment: @ilian Yes it works and thanks. I agree with Jesse that if you post it as an answer it would help more people.

Answer (score 8):

The error is due to the issue being fixed on the server, which involves removing the `CloudObject-10.3.760` paclet so it is no longer downloadable.

Evaluate first

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]
```

and then

```
PacletUpdate["CloudObject"]
```

I have also updated the original [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931) to include this step.