# Mathematica freezes everytime I try to rotate 3D stuff

Tags: plotting, windows

So I created a simple `Plot3D`: `Plot3D[Sin[x]Cos[y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 1, 10}]`
When I try to rotate the plot Mathematica freezes and I can only shut it down with the Task Manager.

My hardware:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Intel i7-4790
- 32 GB Ram
- NVIDIA GTX 960

[image: Problem]

Comment: You should contact support@wolfram.com about this.

Comment: ...and what is your *Mathematica* version?

Comment: Sorry I thought it'd be visible in the gif: 10.4

Comment: I once met a similar situation. wait a while after you get the result then rotate it may solve the problem

Comment: @Wjx I waited 20 minutes but get the same result :/

Comment: Unfortunately...... in this way I don't know the solution either, try report it to WOLFRAM

Comment: It may be worth a try to change the antialiasing quality.  Using the toolbar, Edit -> Preferences will open a popup window.  In that window, choose Appearance -> Graphics, then set the slider to either "No Antialiasing" or "Highest Quality".  It worked for me when I had a similar problem rotating 3D graphics.

Comment: Sadly no change, @Louis

Comment: See [How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default configuration?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) and [Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels)

Comment: It might be worth checking if you have up to date graphic drivers.