# Mathematica 10.4 consuming 100% CPU after startup

Tags: kernel-startup

Whenever I start up a new Mathematica session, I have to restart the kernel do anything.

For example, if I just enter

`1` (or **any** other command)

into a blank notebook, then Mathematica waits and waits and never returns an answer. It uses 100% CPU while doing so, getting stuck on the command (found using `htop`):

`WolframKernel -wstp -mathlink -linkprotocol -SharedMemory -linkconnect -linkname -dnqwp_shm`

To get Mathematica to respond, I have to restart the kernel via:  `Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local` and then `Evaluation -> Start Kernel -> Local`. After this, everything works normally.

---

My operating system is Linux (Arch), the version of Mathematica is 10.4, *though I started noticing this problem earlier (around 10.2?)*.

---

I already tried [Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels), but it does not help (and in any case, the problem is not that Mathematica gets stuck at `Initializing Kernels`).

There seems to be a thread discussing this at: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/344133, but none of the steps help either.

Comment: Did you contact WRI support already? They are the place to go to for such stuff.