# Mathematica 11.0.1 freezes on startup

Tags: kernel-startup

My MMA Installation (11.0.1, Windows 7) newly  freezes the Welcome screen somtimes.

I'm looking/hoping for a similar solution like  [Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)?

Comment: @halirutan Thank you for your helpful answer. I didn't try it yet. Only one hint (reset MMA default) I executed successful(hopefully): Starting MMA  while holding Shift/Strg...

Comment: Shift/Control may not be effective enough. If this is truly an issue it may be necessary to delete _all_ the directories mentioned in the article halirutan points to.

Comment: Otherwise I would recommend upgrading to a more recent release, if you are able to.

Comment: @user6014 Thanks, I will test the Shift/Control workaround  some days. If necessary I will follow your recommandation.