# Mathematica 11.2 freezes when initializing kernel connections

Tags: mathematical-optimization, bugs

I am having this problem (Mathematica freezes when initializing kernel connection)  since about one week:

I found the link
[Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931)

followed the instructions concerning paclets
and it seemd to work the first time then it happened again.
I contacted Wolfram, they suggested to uninstall and reinstall Mathematica.
I did it: same problem. Tried again the paclets solution. No way.

Now I cannot use Mathematica anymore.
Any help?

Comment: What did you install one month ago?

Comment: I upgraded to windows 11