# Mathematica 10.3+ freezes on first evaluation after start-up (Mac)

Tags: mac-os-x

When I launch Mathematica and write the first command and press `Return+Shift`, whatever the command is, it takes forever to evaluate — about two minutes. Immediately after the first evaluation (even if I abort it) everything is back to normal.

If I then restart the kernel, the problem does not come back.

If I *just wait* for a couple of minutes after the start-up, the problem also does not appear.

From these observations, I would conclude that this problem is not related to the kernel (though I'm not a programmer).

I've been seeing this behavior since upgrading to 10.3 and it persists in 10.3.1.

Is this a bug? Is it Mac-only? Is it known?

Comment: What are the stats of you computer? RAM? processor? etc?

Comment: @rcollyer 2 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 4000, SSD memory. Mac OS X 10.11.2

Comment: It might be helpful to check the activity monitor (search for via spotlight) while the issue occurs to see if there is high load on the CPU or RAM

Comment: @Sascha no, almost nothing is happening — 3-4% load from Mathematica.

Comment: I have never experienced this problem on my Mac with Mathematica 10.3.1 or earlier. MacBook Pro: Processor 3 GHz Intel Core i7; Memory 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, 1 TB SSD; Graphics Intel Iris 1536 MB; OS X 10.11.2

Comment: I have a similar problem with almost every program, not just Mathematica, when my Mac comes out of sleep mode (similar specs to Bob Hanlon's, but running OSX 10.10.5 ). My surmise is that when the CPU temperature (using iStat) is below ~40 degree C the machine does not perform well, especially when it needs reading and writing to the SSD. My suspicion is that the problem is in OSX. I once called Apple Care, but they had no clue.

Comment: Take a look here too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57674/12

Comment: Annoyingly, this bug persists in 10.4. (Somewhat of a fix suggested below does work though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This annoying bug has finally been fixed in 11.0

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and solved it by doing this. Just go to the **Preferences**->**Internet Connectivity** and turn off **Allow the Wolfram System to access the Internet**, then relaunch Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Of course, with this setting WolframAlpha doesn't work. It is pretty frustrating that this bug persists in 10.4.

Answer (score 3):

First, try resetting Mathematica by following this article:

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Even if there's no reason why it should work, please try it.

---

If that doesn't work, then try running the Mathematica kernel:

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12414

You should be able to evaluate simple things like 2+2. Can you? If not, are there error messages? Try to evaluate:

```
SystemInformation["Small"]
```

Does that work? What is the output?

---

If none of this works, you may want to contact Wolfram Technical Support by email using this form:

http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical

Comment: Resetting didn't do anything.
It does evaluate everything, but only after a couple minutes since the start-up pass (or if I start and abort the first evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem by turning off the automatic updates in the preferences. Hope it will work for you too!