# When I start Mathematica 11 and do a simple calculation like 2 + 2, it continuous running and never completes

Tags: evaluation, kernel-startup

I'm using *Mathematica* 11 on Mac. When I start *Mathematica* and create a new notebook then do some simple calculation like `2 + 2` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it continues running and never stops. The title of the notebook is `Untitled-1 (Running...)` then. I can use `Abort Evaluation` menu item under the `Evaluation` menu to abort the operation. But after that I still can't do any calculations and the symptom is exactly the same. I have to stop and start the local kernel in order to use it normally. Anyone can help to point me the problem? Thank you.

Comment: If you have not done so already [disable the suggestions bar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121) and try again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I disabled it right now and it still the same.

Comment: Okay.  After carefully making a copy of your configuration files the next step would be a reset as described in http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464 -- please try that.

Comment: If that does not work please report this to official support; it may be a packlet problem like [(92931)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92931/121)

Comment: I think I found the reason. I unchecked "Run kernels at a lower process priority" under the "parallel" tab of the Preference panel and suddenly it works.

Comment: You might post that as a self-answer. I wouldn't have thought of that as the cause.  Do you have another continuous background task running that would occupy your CPU and leave *Mathematica* waiting?

Comment: @OgrishMan That sounds strange, as parallel kernels aren't normally used for this. Instead of changing the process priorities, make sure that "Launch parallel kernels" is set to "when needed".  Also see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57674/12