# Why Mathematica 11.1 crashes without chance to save?

Tags: crash

I am getting really frustrated with Mathematica 11.1. It crashes spontaneously during calculations, typing, editing expressions, etc. In previous versions you could kill the kernel process and still save the notebook with your workings.
Now it just says: "Mathematica 11.1 has stopped working" and your only option is to close the program loosing everything. 
I am saving all variables regularly using `Save["file","`*"]` but have to type in all evaluations again. It never happened in previous versions.
I uploaded the image of the crash here:

[image]

My system is Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit, Dell Optiplex 9010, university site license.

Comment: This is, I think, a question for support. You might get a bit more traction on Wolfram community, too.

Comment: Is the crash random, or can you reproduce it consistently?  If you have 11.1.0, install 11.1.1 (or if you have the license for it, then 11.2.0).  Then try these instructions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57674/12

Comment: At the moment I can only upgrade to 11.1.1, no 11.2.0 available yet. The problem is that the crash is random. You can just type and it crashes. Or you click on the next input and it crashes. It happens once per week on average but you loose a half day work. I don't have a problem with kernel crashes. I often kill the kernel and restart.  The crash in 11.1 kills the notebook too and this is inacceptable.

Comment: Some standard advice: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978. Crashing editors have been such an irritating feature of computer systems my whole life that folks developed the habit of frequent saving and even [added autosave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/is-there-a-notebook-autosave-frequency-configuration) to editors.

Comment: It is quite difficult to surmise what might be going wrong without a clear example that elicits the crashing behavior.